# Why does parented to bone object copy location of tail instead of the head?

Tags: bones, parent, origin

If you parent any object to the bone in pose mode <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and then clear its origin (<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>), object moves to the *Tail*, which is a bit strange, because *Head* is the origin of bone's transformation.

Any purpose why is it made that way?

Answer (score 1):

I guess, this is natural behaviour of the bone. A set of two connected bones (parent+child) means that *Head* of child will copy location of parent's *Tail*.

Same thing with other objects.